# Dynamic Index Match based on text string and 2 criteria

Tags: microsoft-excel

I can't wrap my head around my problem. I have a P&L that shows line items down column A, and across rows different cost centers. However, the line items change, and therefore a specific row reference can't be used in my Index match. (COuld be in row 114 today, but 322 next month). I want to look up BOTH in which row e.g. "Revenue from Operations" is in column A and e.g. Cost center "China" in row 14 , and then return the corresponding value. Cost centers are always in row 14.

Appreciate the help!

Daniel

Comment: share sample data and then show what the outcome would be

Answer (score 0):

Ok so if I understand your question correctly, you want to look across row 14 for e.g "china" and return e.g. "H14" (if H14 = "china"), then look down column A for "Revenue from Operations" and return say "A100" (if A100 = "Revenue from Operations", then combine col(H14) and row(A100) to look up the value at H100.

Lets assume all your numeric data is located at B15:Z1000, your cost centres are B14:Z14 and your line items A15:A1000 then

```
=INDEX(B15:Z1000, MATCH("Revenue from Operations", A15:A1000,0), MATCH("China",B14:Z14,0))
```